# Combine two drivers for Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm currently using this configuration to hide qt messages in the console:

```
Capybara.register_driver :webkit_with_qt_plugin_messages_suppressed do |app|
 Capybara::Webkit::Driver.new(app,Capybara::Webkit::Configuration.to_hash.merge(stderr: WebkitStderrWithQtPluginMessagesSuppressed.new))
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit_with_qt_plugin_messages_suppressed
```

but I also need to ignore ssl errors:

```
Capybara::Driver::Webkit.new({ :ignore_ssl_errors => true})
```

The problem is that if i do

```
Capybara.register_driver :webkit_with_qt_plugin_messages_suppressed do |app|
 Capybara::Webkit::Driver.new(app,Capybara::Webkit::Configuration.to_hash.merge(stderr: WebkitStderrWithQtPluginMessagesSuppressed.new))
 Capybara::Webkit::Driver.new(app, :ignore_ssl_errors => true)
end
```

the test passes but I see qt messages.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do what you want

```
Capybara.register_driver :webkit_with_qt_plugin_messages_suppressed do |app|
     Capybara::Webkit::Driver.new(app,
        Capybara::Webkit::Configuration.to_hash.merge(
          stderr: WebkitStderrWithQtPluginMessagesSuppressed.new,
          ignore_ssl_errors: true)
     )
end
```

Comment: yes, this is what I want. But i can't understand why if I'm using your code, the test fails (even if it is right), and if I use `Capybara.register_driver :webkit_with_qt_plugin_messages_suppressed do |app|
  Capybara::Webkit::Driver.new(app,Capybara::Webkit::Configuration.to_hash.merge(stderr: WebkitStderrWithQtPluginMessagesSuppressed.new))
  Capybara::Webkit::Driver.new(app).tap {|d| d.browser.ignore_ssl_errors }
end` the test passes (but with qt messaged showed in console)

Comment: Your example is creating 2 drivers - and returning the second one -- the first one just gets ignored -- if that is how ignore_ssl_errors is set rather than as an option to the driver then you would want    Capybara::Webkit::Driver.new(app, Capybara::Webkit::Configuration.to_hash.merge(stderr: WebkitStderrWithQtPluginMessageSuppressed.new)).tap { |d| d.browser.ignore_ssl_errors}